# Gembox, colorify Excel row

Tags: c#, excel, gembox-spreadsheet

As stated in the title i would like to use Gembox to colorify an entire row in a Excell document with a color selected at runtime.

I have tried the following code :

```
      ef.LoadXls("path"), XlsOptions.PreserveAll);
      ef.Worksheets[0].Rows[myRowIndex].Style.FillPattern.SetPattern ( FillPatternStyle.None , Color.Black , selectedColor );
```

but seem not work (i have no exception but row remain white), any suggestion to do what i need ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of *FillPatternStyle.None* use *FillPatternStyle.Solid*, try the following:

```
// When solid is specified, the PatternForegroundColor is the only color that's rendered.
ef.Worksheets[0].Rows[myRowIndex].Style
    .FillPattern
    .SetPattern(FillPatternStyle.Solid, selectedColor, Color.Empty);
```